# React Native: how to get the names of all the albums

Tags: ios, react-native, photos

I would like the user to select an Album and then display the photos of it in react-native. There is the CameraRoll and it has the ability to filter by groupName, but I did not find a way of how to retrieve these groupNames. Does anybody know how to do this, or do I need to write a native plugin?

Answer (score 1):

well, at least you can select a lot of items and group...

```
import R from 'ramda';
import { CameraRoll } from 'react-native';
let groupNames;
CameraRoll.getPhotos({
    first:20000
}).then(
    (result) => {
        const groupNamesAr = R.map(
            (item) => {
                return item.node.group_name;
            }
        )(result.edges)
        groupNames = R.countBy((i)=>i)(groupNamesAr);
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker it will let you select an image from any album.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently possible. See [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10666) issue in the official repository. You can upvote [this](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/get-image-folder-name-list-and-get-images-from-chosen-folder) feature request if you're looking for this to be implemented.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is `MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync()`